# PHP and MySQL compare data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, while-loop

I have a database and in that database I have an `ipbans` table and then i also have a users table. the users table has a column called `lastip` and the `ipbans` table has a table called ip.

I need to compare the lastip to the ip columns and if they both match to display the data, i have done it in mysql but i don't know how to add it to my existing while loop that looks for if the user is banned or not.

```
SELECT  
IF((SELECT INET_NTOA(b.ip) FROM ipbans AS b WHERE INET_NTOA(b.ip) = p.LastIP) IS NULL, concat('<font color=blue>', p.LastIP, '</font>'), concat('<font color=red>', p.LastIP, '</font>')) AS IPv4 
FROM players AS p WHERE p.Banned = 1
```

doing this makes the IP blue if it matches and the IP red if it doesn't, but I want to echo this data with the username.

EDIT:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `players` WHERE  `Banned` = 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $username = $row['Username'];
    $lastip = $row['LastIP'];
    $level = $row['Level'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$username</td>";
    if ($lastip > 2){
        echo "<td>$lastip</td>";
    } else {
        echo '<td>IP not found in IPBans!</td>';
    }
        echo "<td>$level</td>";
        echo "<td>Location</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
```

I currently have the above as my query, it goes into the players table and lists the players that are banned, from there I want to get the last IP that they've logged in with (already logged with LastIP column) and i want to compare it with the ipbans table and only display the users whos IP's match the ipbans table and the LastIP.

Comment: add the column `username` ?

Comment: i already have a username column, you don't understand my question
i want to compare the IP address in the lastip column in the users table with the IP in the 'ip' column in the ipbans table and only display the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your two queries into one like:

```
SELECT
    p.Username, p.Level,
    IF((SELECT INET_NTOA(b.ip) FROM ipbans AS b WHERE INET_NTOA(b.ip) = p.LastIP) IS NULL,
        concat('<font color=blue>', p.LastIP, '</font>'),
        concat('<font color=red>', p.LastIP, '</font>')) AS LastIP
FROM players AS p
WHERE p.Banned = 1
```

Though I would personally prefer to generate the HTML code in the PHP, rather than in SQL.